# Apply a brush on a path in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, path, brush

Hy. I want to create something like this:

[image]

using path. I want to draw a line in fact and on that line I want to apply a rainbow effect like this one. Some time I want to have 2 colors in the rainbow, other times 6,7 it depends.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Hello. There is actually an abundance of tutorial that you can find using Google. Do you have a problem with a specific step? What have you tried so far?

Comment: While there isn't a dynamic method for giving a layer multiple strokes, you can kind of fake it in some situations by using layer styles: `drop shadow, inner shadow, inner glow, outer glow, stroke` and of course you can get 6th stroke by adding a stroke to a shape. You might be better off just making one line and duplicate it multiple times... or use illustrator and import it to PS as vector smart object, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

it's pretty simple. I'll break it down into steps and you can tell me where/if you encounter a problem.

1. Make sure you have your brush panel open.
2. Now create a new shape,  one that you want to use as a brush. For e.g. Here you'd need to create 4-5 squares placed next to each other, each of different color. It's like a small chunk of the rainbow you want to create.
3. Select all and drag it to an empty space in the brushes panel. 
   3.1 or alternatively, select the whole thing, go to brushes panel and open the drop down on the top right corner of the panel. There should be an option saying "create new brush".  Choose 'pattern brush'... And you are good to go.
4. Next create the stroke you want. Apply the newly created brush style to it.

Cheers.